# How do I solve this ice puzzle?

Tags: epic-battle-fantasy-4

So far, I've figured out that one of the blocks needs to support the others (so they can get into position).  The problem is, that block tends to get stuck too often, and I've already racked my brain trying to solve this.

[image]

How should I solve this puzzle?

Edit: Yes, the blocks slide, as they are made out of ice.

Comment: To give this a more descriptive title, can you provide the level/stage/puzzle number?

Comment: I do look at the title when I upvote/downvote a question. This one will get an up if the title can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the game here right now, but I assume that a block will glide when pushed until it hits something.

Let's name the four blocks A, B, C, D(from left to right)
Going from these assumptions the following steps are needed.
**Bold** steps place a block on it's final place

1. B down
2. **B left**
3. D up
4. A up
5. A right
6. **A down**
7. D right
8. C up
9. **C right**
10. D down
11. **D left**

All blocks are now aligned with the indications.